# Windows Server 2012 on RAID 1 stuck in Automatic Repair after motherboard change

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012

The motherboard with Intel H87 chipset (with Intel Rapid Storage Technology) stopped working. It was replaced with MBO with H97 chipset. 
OS and data are in separate RAID 1 configurations. New MBO recognizes disks in RAID, sees Windows partition as bootable.
But on attempted boot, it instantly goes to Automatic Repair mode. Same for booting in safe mode.

I have tried following from repair console, as suggested [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87df48fd-0ae3-4bc2-b3f4-b39aea19215a/windows-server-2012-essentials-stuck-in-automatic-repair-loop?forum=smallbusinessserver2011essentials).

> bootrec /fixmbr, fixboot

I have tried copying registry files one folder up, as suggested [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Windows_Server_2012/Q_28448565.html)

No effect.

It also won't boot if one disk is removed from RAID - it displays RAID warning, as it should, and again goes to Automatic Repair.

What are your suggestions, is it possible to boot this without reinstalling Windows?